# Rails Scope for association of 0 size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having trouble figuring out the scope method for all the Foos that have no Bars.  That is:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_may :bars

end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :foo

end
```

I'd like to write a scope method that returns me all the foos that have no bars. Something like:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_may :bars

  scope :has_no_bars, includes(:bars).where("COUNT(foo.bars) = 0")

end
```

But I don't understand the appropriate syntax.  Any help?  Happy to use a MetaWhere solution if easier.

Comment: Can you afford to store the cache count of bars in the Foo table? (Using a counter cache)

Comment: hmm..that could work, but I'd like to know what the actual query should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need either a sub-select or an outer join + group + unique to solve your problem. AFAIK that is not possible with Rails' AR.

An approximation would be to use AR's [counter-cache](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) feature and make your query as simple as

```
scope :has_no_bars, where("bars_count = 0")
```

This isn't 100% correct relation-wise but saves you a lot of work and also scales much better.

Comment: okay, so in the in-between time, i found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676588/creating-a-named-scope-for-no-children-in-a-has-many-association

which uses a subselect. And you're saying, performance wise that sucks and just use the counter-cache?

Comment: follow up - what's the downside to counter-cacheing 'everything'? or does counter-cacheing count as a best practice?

Comment: From a performance perspective a sub-select is always dangerous (as the DB can't optimize the query) while a counter-cache column comes for free (only the cache has to be updated when associated records are created). But the counter-cache might not be 100% correct (might be off by a few numbers should you have updated a record not through Rails or have skipped the callbacks).